# Twitter bot returns "undefined" values when hosted on Heroku but works fine on my local machine

Tags: node.js, heroku

I've this Twitter bot that tweets out info on stock trades, whenever I run the bot from VS Code it works fine and tweets the values I want. Now I need to host it on Heroku but when I do and the script executes the values that are tweeted end up as `undefined`, [see image](https://ibb.co/j8rSY1C). This is happening to `priceModule` and `nameModule` and I don't understand why, its working perfectly locally, Is there a fix for this?

**Index.js**

```
// MODULES
const rwClient = require("./TwitterClient.js");
const cronjob = require("cron").CronJob;
const priceModule = require("./price");
const nameModule = require("./name");

(async () => {

    // Async function that creates the Tweet
    const tweet = async () => {
        try {
            await rwClient.v2.tweet(
                "Name: " + await nameModule() + '\n' +
                "Amount Purchased: " + await priceModule() + '\n'
            );

        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error)
        }
    }

    console.log(
        "Name: " + await nameModule() + '\n' +
        "Amount Purchased: " + await priceModule() + '\n'
    );

    tweet();
    console.log("Tweet executed");

    // CronJob, executes every 6 hours
    const job = new cronjob("0 */4 * * *", () => {
        tweet();
        console.log("Next tweet executed");
    });

    job.start();
  
})();
```

**nameModule.js**

```
// MODULES
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

// Url where we get and scrape the data from
const url = "https://www.sec.gov/edgar/search/#/dateRange=30d&category=custom&forms=4";

let browser;
module.exports = () => (async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const $ = (...args) => page.waitForSelector(...args);
  const text = async (...args) =>
    (await $(...args)).evaluate(el => el.textContent.trim());
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  await page.reload({waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  const info = {
    secTableEN: await text(".table td.entity-name"),
    secTableFiled: await text(".table td.filed"),
    secTableLink: await text(".table td.filetype"),
  };

  return info.secTableEN;
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

**priceModule**

```
// MODULES
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

// Url where we get and scrape the data from
const url = "https://www.sec.gov/edgar/search/#/dateRange=30d&category=custom&forms=4";

let browser;
module.exports = () => (async () => {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const [page] = await browser.pages();
    const ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36";
    await page.setUserAgent(ua);
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded", timeout: 0});
    await page.reload({waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
    const responseP = page.waitForResponse(res =>
      res.status() === 200 && res.url().endsWith(".xml")
    );
    const a = await page.waitForSelector(".filetype .preview-file");
    await a.click();
    const html = await (await responseP).text();
    await page.evaluate(html => document.body.outerHTML = html, html);
    const price = await page.$$eval(".FormText", els =>
      els.find(e => e.textContent.trim() === "$")
        .parentNode
        .textContent
        .trim()
    );

    return price;

  })()
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
    .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

**Activity log from Heroku**

```
2022-11-15T12:44:00.060455+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at ChromeLauncher.executablePath (/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:166:25)
2022-11-15T12:44:00.060455+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at ChromeLauncher.launch (/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:70:37)
2022-11-15T12:44:00.060455+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at async /app/numShares.js:9:15
2022-11-15T12:44:00.060456+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at async CJ.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:39:46)
2022-11-15T12:44:00.060711+00:00 app[worker.1]: Error: Could not find Chromium (rev. 1056772). This can occur if either
2022-11-15T12:44:00.060711+00:00 app[worker.1]:  1. you did not perform an installation before running the script (e.g. `npm install`) or
2022-11-15T12:44:00.060711+00:00 app[worker.1]:  2. your cache path is incorrectly configured (which is: /app/.cache/puppeteer).
2022-11-15T12:44:00.060712+00:00 app[worker.1]: For (2), check out our guide on configuring puppeteer at https://pptr.dev/guides/configuration.
2022-11-15T12:44:00.060712+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at ChromeLauncher.resolveExecutablePath (/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ProductLauncher.js:120:27)
2022-11-15T12:44:00.060712+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at ChromeLauncher.executablePath (/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:166:25)
2022-11-15T12:44:00.060713+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at ChromeLauncher.launch (/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:70:37)
2022-11-15T12:44:00.060713+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at async /app/price.js:9:15
2022-11-15T12:44:00.060713+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at async CJ.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:39:66)
2022-11-15T12:44:00.060953+00:00 app[worker.1]: Error: Could not find Chromium (rev. 1056772). This can occur if either
2022-11-15T12:44:00.060954+00:00 app[worker.1]:  1. you did not perform an installation before running the script (e.g. `npm install`) or
2022-11-15T12:44:00.060954+00:00 app[worker.1]:  2. your cache path is incorrectly configured (which is: /app/.cache/puppeteer).
2022-11-15T12:44:00.060954+00:00 app[worker.1]: For (2), check out our guide on configuring puppeteer at https://pptr.dev/guides/configuration.
2022-11-15T12:44:00.060954+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at ChromeLauncher.resolveExecutablePath (/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ProductLauncher.js:120:27)
2022-11-15T12:44:00.060955+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at ChromeLauncher.executablePath (/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:166:25)
2022-11-15T12:44:00.060955+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at ChromeLauncher.launch (/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:70:37)
2022-11-15T12:44:00.060955+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at async /app/stock.js:9:15
2022-11-15T12:44:00.060955+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at async CJ.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:40:30)
2022-11-15T12:44:00.061194+00:00 app[worker.1]: Error: Could not find Chromium (rev. 1056772). This can occur if either
2022-11-15T12:44:00.061195+00:00 app[worker.1]:  1. you did not perform an installation before running the script (e.g. `npm install`) or
2022-11-15T12:44:00.061195+00:00 app[worker.1]:  2. your cache path is incorrectly configured (which is: /app/.cache/puppeteer).
2022-11-15T12:44:00.061195+00:00 app[worker.1]: For (2), check out our guide on configuring puppeteer at https://pptr.dev/guides/configuration.
2022-11-15T12:44:00.061195+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at ChromeLauncher.resolveExecutablePath (/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ProductLauncher.js:120:27)
2022-11-15T12:44:00.061196+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at ChromeLauncher.executablePath (/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:166:25)
2022-11-15T12:44:00.061196+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at ChromeLauncher.launch (/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:70:37)
2022-11-15T12:44:00.061196+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at async /app/date.js:9:13
2022-11-15T12:44:00.061197+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at async CJ.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:41:28)
2022-11-15T12:44:00.061227+00:00 app[worker.1]: New insider trade! (form 4 filed)
2022-11-15T12:44:00.061227+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2022-11-15T12:44:00.061228+00:00 app[worker.1]: undefined bought undefined shares at $undefined
2022-11-15T12:44:00.061228+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2022-11-15T12:44:00.061228+00:00 app[worker.1]: Amount Purchased: $NaN
2022-11-15T12:44:00.061229+00:00 app[worker.1]: Stock: undefined
2022-11-15T12:44:00.061229+00:00 app[worker.1]: Date: undefined
2022-11-15T12:44:00.061229+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2022-11-15T12:44:01.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user jojoamankwa@gmail.com
2022-11-15T12:44:38.942638+00:00 app[api]: Release v8 created by user jojoamankwa@gmail.com
2022-11-15T12:44:38.942638+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 2db65223 by user jojoamankwa@gmail.com
2022-11-15T12:44:40.624181+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Restarting
2022-11-15T12:44:40.626042+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to starting
2022-11-15T12:44:39.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-11-15T12:44:41.596325+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2022-11-15T12:44:41.950594+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 143
2022-11-15T12:44:44.285628+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2022-11-15T12:44:45.072715+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-11-15T12:44:53.176410+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Restarting
2022-11-15T12:44:53.191437+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to starting
2022-11-15T12:44:54.322495+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2022-11-15T12:44:54.589561+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 143
2022-11-15T12:44:55.711588+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2022-11-15T12:44:56.492554+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

Comment: The site you are scraping probably has protections in place to prevent such activity. It's common to block requests from IP address blocks that belong to cloud providers (or to serve them up different content). Have you inspected the response you're getting? Is scraping this site permitted under its terms of service?

Comment: Well its a public registry, so I'd guess that something like scraping would be 100% allowed. Its been working fine on my local machine thus far so I was thinking its a problem specific to Heroku.

Comment: [Apparently it is not permitted](https://www.sec.gov/privacy): 'The SEC does not allow "unclassified" bots or automated tools to crawl the site. Any request that has been identified as part of an unclassified bot or an automated tool outside of the acceptable policy will be managed to ensure fair access for all users.' I suggest you respect their policy.

Comment: Unbelievable. Alright I guess

Comment: The actual problem appears to be that Puppeteer isn't able to find Chromium on the Heroku instance, so it throws an error. It then skips over the rest of your code to the catch block, logs out the error, and then logs to console. But the variables haven't been set since that code got skipped, so you get undefined.

Comment: You may need to install the [google chrome buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome) or similar

Answer (score 0):

As the logs clearly states - it's not a problem with `twitter bot` but rather `puppeteer over Heroku`

Why? Because `puppeteer` is a complex module that requires customized builds during installation. Your hosted machine is limited (in terms of permissions) WAY more than your local machine - and that's why you cant really pin-point the problem from your own machine

Luckily for you, both `Heroku` and `puppeteer` are commonly used solutons and that is why there is a buildpack called `puppeteer-heroku-buildpack` that does just that.

I recommend that you follow [these steps](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack) and give it a spin

**Edit:**

From your logs it also seems that chromium is not properly configured. Please note that using `Heroku` requires some configuration (it is NOT as `chrome headless buildpack`) that can be found [here](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/minted/heroku-buildpack-chrome-headless)

Ensure to perform all these prerequisites and only then install `puppeteer`

Comment: I have added the Puppeteer buildpack and its code, still getting the same problem

Comment: recommend to re-deploy in another instance and verify all the flags (such as `no-sandbox`) and rest of configuration set properly

Comment: What do you mean by re-deploy to a different instance?

Comment: use a different machine (aka instance) in Heroku by using `heroku create` from the cli (as mentioned in documentation or use `buildpacks:add` to an already existing instance

Comment: So should I use this code here? ``browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: [
      '--no-sandbox',
      '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
    ],
  });``

Comment: yes please. after configuring both chrome and puppeteer setup - it should work with these flags

Comment: Still getting the same error of `could not find Chromium`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a different API, given Chris's diligent reading of SEC Terms and Services. Alphavantage looks like a good, simple, free API to use for your needs:

https://www.alphavantage.co/

Cheers!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).